# RecyclerView position at the fragment level

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have a fragment that contains a Recyclerview (along with ViewHolder and Adapter).  The onClick handler is defined inside ViewHolder, but I would like to query the position of item selected in the fragment level.

I can save the item position to fragment's member variable using getAdapterPosition() from within the ViewHolder's onClick but is there a direct way to get the ViewHolder or position clicked from the fragment level? Ideally I would rather the ViewHolder not know anything about the fragment.

Comment: Have you considered using custom listeners (interfaces) for forwarding the onClick from ViewHolder via RecyclerView to Fragment? This is how I solved a similar problem.

Comment: @CoenB Could you illustrate?

Comment: Check my awnser for an example

Answer (score 0):

You could use multiple listeners (interfaces) to transport the clicked position back from your `ViewHolder`s to your `Fragment` via your `RecyclerView`. Following is a minimalized example of what I mean: basically you let your Fragment listen to your RecyclerView, which in turn listens to your ViewHolders beeing clicked.

Hope this helps you find a way to solve your problem. Don't know if it is the best way, but it worked for me and I like this communication.

YourViewHolder.java

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        for (ViewHolderListener l : listeners) {
            l.onViewHolderClicked(getLayoutPosition())
...
public interface ViewHolderListener() {
    void onViewHolderClicked(int position);
}
```

YourRecyclerView.java

```
public class YourRecyclerView ... implements YourViewHolder.ViewHolderListener {
...
    @Override
    public void onViewHolderClicked(int position) {
        for (RecyclerViewListener l : listeners) {
            l.onViewClicked(position);
    ...

public interface RecyclerViewListener {
    void onViewClicked(int position);
}
```

YourFragment.java

```
public class YourFragment ... implements YourRecyclerView.RecyclerViewListener {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onViewClicked(int position) {
        // Here you do whatever you want with the clicked view's position
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is there code that adds to the listener list? I am not seeing how the call gets propagated up.

Comment: In this example listeners is just a ArrayList. So you can create a simple method like `public void addOnViewClickListener(OnViewClickListener l) { listeners.add(l); }`. Than on creation of your ViewHolder you call `vh.addOnViewClickListener(this)` (this beeing your RecyclerView).